# PayPal IPN - "Update your integration before 1/18/2017" email. How to identify incorrect data in my IPN code?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I've been using the PayPal's IPN system for over several years. I have a PHP script that's been processing online eCommerce payments on my web site without any issues.

Today I received the following email from PayPal:

> **Update your integration before 1/18/2017.**
>
> Effective 1/18/2017, your PayPal Payments Standard (also known as
>   Website Payments Standard or HTML buttons) integration will be
>   affected by updates we’re making to enhance the checkout process.
>
> We’ve identified your integration as passing either invalid or
>   incorrect data to PayPal in one or more of your payment buttons. To
>   ensure your payments continue to process, you’ll need to update your
>   integration as soon as possible.
>
> **What’s Needed**
>
> Please check out these [FAQs](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067&expand=true&locale=en_US) for more information on common integration
>   issues. Additional details can be found in our Developer documentation
>   [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web).
>
> Here are some of the benefits you’ll receive with your updated
>   integration:
>
> *sales blah-blah...*
>
> As always, if you need help or have any questions, give us a call or
>   visit our [Help Center](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/home).
>
> Thank you for being a PayPal customer.

I checked my integration script and it is passing their `"most common problems"` [from here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067&expand=true&locale=en_US).

So my question is, did anyone figure out how to test your IPN script with their new update to know what exactly [`has been identified as passing incorrect or invalid data to PayPal`](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067&expand=true&locale=en_US)?

Comment: It was a false alarm. That idiotic service sent out that message to "everyone" even if the IPN script had no issues at all. Man, time to leave PayPal!